# Activate and deactivate plugin automatically

Tags: plugins, functions, automation

How I can Activate and deactivate plugin automatically?
For example,
I want the "Yoast Seo" plugin to be active only on Monday, Wednesday, Friday, Saturday and the other days deactivated.
How can I do it?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of running this through a schedule event in WordPress, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Here is a snippet that hopefully will get you there:

```
<?php
  
  if(!wp_next_scheduled('daily_plugin_check')){
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'daily_plugin_check' );
  }

  add_action( 'daily_plugin_check', 'toggle_plugins' );

  function toggle_plugins() {
    switch(date('D')){
      case 'Mon' :
      case 'Wed' :
      case 'Fri' :
        // Could be an array or a single string
        $plugin_to_activate = 'akismet/akismet.php';
        $plugin_to_deactivate = 'akismet/akismet.php';
        break;
      // Continue with each day you'd like to activate / deactive them
    }

    if(!function_exists('activate_plugin')){
      require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
    }

    if(!empty($plugin_to_activate){
      // If $plugin_to_activate is an array, then you can foreach of it
      if(!is_plugin_active($plugin_to_activate)){
        activate_plugin($plugin_to_activate);
      }
    }

    if(!empty($plugin_to_deactivate){
      // If $plugin_to_activate is an array, then you can foreach of it
      if(is_plugin_active($plugin_to_deactivate)){
        deactivate_plugins($plugin_to_deactivate);
      }
    }

  }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer. One caveat is that this relies on CRON, which can be shut down depending on the environment being used. I've banged my head against that one before!

Comment: @christopherjones looks very promising. I added your code to wp-cron.php but i need a little help how and where to modify it.
For instance I need to add days and hours;
Mondays GMT +1 9 pm till 6 am ACTIVATED
Tuesdays GMT +1 6:01 am till 8:59 DEACTIVATED Any help is welcome!
Rob

Comment: @user9088656 you should not modify WP Core files, `wp-admin` `wp-includes` and the files in the root of the WP folder should never be modified ( with the exception of `wp-config.php` ). Otherwise, if you have a new question, you should create a new question, don't post it as a solution to somebody elses question

Answer (score 0):

You can mange this by adding the following to your `functions.php` file.

Checking todays timestamp for the days you want the plugin active - on the off days the plugin is disabled.

```
$timestamp = time(); // Timestamp
$day       = date( 'D', $timestamp ); // Get day from timestamp
$active    = array( 'Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri', 'Sat' ); // Days plugin to be active
if ( in_array( $day, $active, true ) ) { // Yoast SEO is active
    activate_plugin( '/wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' );
} else { // Yoast SEO is deactivated
    deactivate_plugins( '/wordpress-seo/wp-seo.php' );
}
```

It uses `activate_plugin()` to activate and `deactivate_plugins()` to deactivate the plugin.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/deactivate_plugins/

Comment: This is nice and clean, but omits the fact that `function.php` will not run code unless the site is hit. This could cause some potential misses. The other answer here using `wp_schedule_event()` uses CRON, and does not rely on "outside" forces.

Comment: @NathanPowell Good point!